# Безопасность формы обратной связи

Tags: безопасность, форма

На сайте хочу сделать форму, в которой гостевой юзер (не залогиненный на сайте) задает вопрос и оставляет свой e-mail для получения ответа.

Если почта введена неверно, либо указана чужая, то ответ придет куда не надо и произойдет утечка информации. Как от этого защититься?

Подтверждение права владения почтой по ссылке на эту почту вынуждает пользователя делать дополнительные действия, хотелось бы без них обойтись. И кроме того, если кто-то активируют ссылку, присланную по ошибке, то и ответ он также получит.

Answer (score 1):

**Если вам действительно будут писать** в такую форму с обязательным подтверждением email, то делайте так:

**Вариант 1.** Сохраняйте юзеру куку в браузер с уникальным содержимым (предупредите пользователя, что кука должна быть сохранена для подтверждения), отправляйте пользователю письмо с уникальной ссылкой на указанный email, при переходе по ссылки из письма проверяйте наличие куки с нужным содержимым.

**Вариант 2.** При отправке данных из формы выводите на экран пользователю проверочный код с просьбой запомнить его для подтверждения подлинности email. При переходе по ссылке из письма просите пользователя ввести этот проверочный код.

Answer (score 0):

Отправляйте на эмейл ссылку на информацию, для доступа к ней необходимо ввести свое имя(не логин), который писался при оставлении эмейла. Он и будет служить для определения пользователя.

Например я делаю запрос на получение данных, для этого я пишу свое имя - **Константин** и свой эмейл **test@mail.ru**. На почту приходит ссылка, открыв которую вы просите ввести пользователя ввести свое имя( для меня это Константин ). Нигде больше имя не используется.

Главное условие - посторонний человек не знающий всех обстоятельств задавания вопроса не сможет получить ответ - выполнено.

Похожим образом в Отечественную партизаны-агенты друг друга узнавали не используя заумных схем аунтификации.

P.S.: советую почитать про разницу между [аунтификацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5) и [авторизацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)